# Regex number of matches is always zero

Tags: objective-c, regex

I want to check a UITextField text with a format like "G12-123456".
Rules are simple;
First character must be upper case letter.
The 2nd and 3rd must be number.
Fourth must be "-" character.
The last six must be only numbers.
Below code not work, number of matches always returns zero.

I also tried regex as "[A-Z0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6}"

```
NSString * myRegex = @"[A-Z][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]";

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:myRegex
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string
                                                    options:NSMatchingReportProgress
                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

This one works with same code [^a-zA-Z0-9] -> Check whether an NSString contains a special character and a digit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'd better use `NSPredicate * tst = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", myRegex]; if ([tst evaluateWithObject:txt]) { /* GOOD */ }` -  that way you will also anchor the regex.

Answer (score 0):

First of all basically your code is supposed to work.

However both options are nonsensical. If you want to check for uppercase letter you must not pass `NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive` and `NSMatchingReportProgress` affects only the block based API.

In both cases pass `0.`

The pattern can be written more efficient

```
NSString *myRegex = @"[A-Z]\\d{2}-\\d{6}";

NSError *error;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:myRegex
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:&error];
if {error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
} else {
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string
                                                    options:0
                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    NSLog(@"%lu", numberOfMatches);
}
```

If the regex must match the entire string add the start - end anchors.

```
NSString *myRegex = @"^[A-Z]\\d(2)-\\d{6}$";
```

If `numberOfMatches` is zero please check if the hyphen character is the standard one (ASCII `45`, hex `0x2D`).

Comment: Then your string is wrong. I updated the answer, please read the last sentence.

Comment: Do you mean that I should get the ASCI value of the NSSring (UITextField text).

Comment: Yes, create an NSData object from the string and print it. The hyphen character must be 2D. Your test string in the question is `<4731322d 31323334 3536>`

Comment: But numberOfMatchesInString needs an NSString parameter, how can I pass NSData to it?

Comment: Once again, the regex is working unless the hyphen character (`-`) is not `0x2d`. The data dump is only for testing purpose.